# Cron job set up in local timezone gets incorrectly converted to UTC (using Serverless Local Schedule)

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a schedule for job set up as follows using `serverless-local-schedule`:

```
- schedule:
    rate: cron(1 0 20 * ? *)
    timezone: Asia/Tokyo
```

It is supposed to run at 00:01 on the 20th day of each month. However, the schedule expression for the trigger that actually appears in AWS console looks like this:

```
cron(1 15 20 * ? *)
```

Time difference is calculated correctly (it's a 9-hour difference), but change of day is not taken into account - it should be:

```
cron(1 15 19 * ? *)
```

The job did run a day later than supposed to. What might be the cause of this issue?